# How to change File Inode Change Date/Time of the file via exiftool?

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I changed creation date of the mp4 via `touch -t 207012121515 video.mp4`, but *exiftool* gives me File Inode Change Date/Time for today.

How to change File Inode Change Date/Time of the file via exiftool ?

Comment: What is the name of the actual tag you wish to change?  Use the command `exiftool -s -File:All video.mp4` to list the tag names rather than description.  You can then check on the [Mac OS Tag names](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/MacOS.html#MDItem) page to see if exiftool can write it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, for some reason I assumed you were on a Mac and was looking at the Mac tags.  I think the tag you want to change is `FileInodeChangeDate`.  Exiftool does not have the ability to change this value. [See Extra Tags](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Extra.html).